Laravel Fortify add Page befor two-factor-challenge
i got the issue that the user is not gettting redirected to the two-factor-challenge page after he confirms which method he wants to get the TOTP code.
if sms email or authentication app
after confirmation which method -> the user should get redirected to the two-factor-challenge page
`namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
class TwoFactorController extends Controller
{
public function setup2FAMethode(Request $request)
{
// Validierung der Eingabe, sicherstellen, dass eine gültige Methode gewählt wurde
$request->validate([
'totp_methode' => 'required|in:totp,sms,email',
]);
    // Speichern der ausgewählten Methode in der Session
    session(['selected_totp_method' => $request->input('totp_methode')]);

    // Nach der Auswahl den Benutzer zur Two-Factor-Challenge-Seite weiterleiten
    return redirect()->route('two-factor.login');
}

}   `
`Route::middleware('auth')->group(function () {
// Zwei-Faktor-Setup
Route::get('/setup', [TwoFactorController::class, 'setup'])->name('setup');
// Zwei-Faktor-Anmelde-Routen
Route::post('/setup', [TwoFactorController::class, 'setup2FAMethode'])->name('setup2FA.post');

// Fortify's zwei-Faktor-Authentifizierungsseiten
Route::get('/two-factor-challenge', function () {
    return view('auth.two-factor-challenge');
})->name('two-factor.challenge');

});`
